# FCN -8 training

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

How do i train a fcn-8 model from start for only one class as a classified output instead of 21 classes.
i used the fcn model as mentioned in https://github.com/mzaradzki/neuralnets/blob/master/vgg_segmentation_keras/fcn8s_tvg_for_rnncrf.ipynb 
The output of above model was noisy,i even tried for fcn16 but the result remain the same.
So how do i train the model so that i acheive desired result

Comment: What do you mean when you say noisy? Can you provide sample images? There are things to consider when training. If you used that model as is, without preloaded weights, your model might be noisy.